# OnClickListener in MyCustomView which extends SurfaceView

Tags: android, surfaceview, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener, touch-event

I have an extended view from `SurfaceView` like this:

```
public class MyView extends SurfaceView implements View.OnClickListener {

  public MyView(Context context)
     {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        setOnClickListener(this);
     }

  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()){
        case DOWN OR UP OR MOVE: <-- I do something here like move and drag and drop and 
        // any related behavior to MyView 
    }
    invalidate();

    return true;
  }
```

Now I implemented OnClickListener and set it in my constructor.
**OnClick** method:

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v){
    Log.e("as", "clicked");
 }
```

But onClick method never not called. How can I solved that?

When replaced `return true;` with `return super.onTouchEvent(event);` my onClick method called, but when I want to move my custom view, onClick method again called and this is not my porpuse. 
I want only when I tapped my custom view, onClick called, and when moved it not called.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably your onTouch Listener. You are overriding and not dealing with the onClick possibility. Additionally you are consuming the event with a return **true** so the onClick will never be called.

Remember that onClick is dealt in onTouchEvent implemented in the original view class.

You can check more info at:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)

where you can read:

> public boolean **onTouchEvent** (MotionEvent event)
>
> Added in API level 1 Implement this method to handle touch screen
>   motion events.
>
> If this method is used to detect click actions, it is recommended that
>   the actions be performed by implementing and calling performClick().
>   This will ensure consistent system behavior, including:
>
> - obeying click sound preferences dispatching OnClickListener calls
> - handling ACTION_CLICK when accessibility features are enabled
> - Parameters event    The motion event.
>
> Returns True if the event was
>   handled, false otherwise.

Since you want to choose when click is performed, you should implement the performClick (like it  states in the link I have referenced).